# Bazel + C++ project: how to specify working directory for 'run' command

Tags: c++, bazel, mediapipe

I'm trying to run a *bazel* target with `bazel run` command from workspace root. And I want to pass relative path as an argument to this target. Currently it doesn't recognize this pass, whilst manual run from console works fine.

So I conclude that bazel`s working dir differs from workspace root at this point .

I have checked for bazel docs, google, and didn't find an explicit way to specify working directory for run command. Does anybody know proper way to do that? Thanks!

P.S.:
Namely I'm trying to run [mediapipe iris example](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/iris.html), which I build with following command (from project root):

```sh
bazel build -c opt --define MEDIAPIPE_DISABLE_GPU=1 mediapipe/examples/desktop/iris_tracking:iris_tracking_cpu
```

Then if I run it manually (also from project root) it works fine:

```sh
GLOG_logtostderr=1 bazel-bin/mediapipe/examples/desktop/hand_tracking/hand_tracking_gpu   --calculator_graph_config_file=mediapipe/graphs/hand_tracking/hand_tracking_mobile.pbtxt
```

Now if I run it with `bazel run` it fails:

```
bazel run -c dbg --define MEDIAPIPE_DISABLE_GPU=1 mediapipe/examples/desktop/iris_tracking:iris_tracking_cpu -- --calculator_graph_config_file=mediapipe/graphs/iris_tracking/iris_tracking_cpu.pbtxt
```

Not, that using `$PWD` in front of graph path doesn't help, for mediapipe engine still relies on relative path and proper CWD value.

Comment: I have built up simple bazel app which prints current directory. And I prints me following:

"/private/var/tmp/_bazel_stepan/5fb8b1321583495e8a465a1758c5a8e4/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/main/hello-world.runfiles/__main__"

...Oh... this is what I always supposed to be a working dir (sarcasm).

Comment: After a while I discovered following. Bazel uses "sandboxing" thing. Thus... whenever your run "bazel run" it runs file in semi-isolated sandbox (they use term "hermetic" run). And somehow it is possible to disable sandbox, by passing special tag into build rules. Currently I'm trying to play with "no-sandbox" but it seems that you have to clean it, otherwise it still uses sandbox.

Comment: Well, I defined following in "cc_binary" rule: 'tags = ["no-sandbox", "no-cache", "no-remote"]'.... and it didn't help. So far no ideas.

Comment: You could wrap the program in a sh_binary that takes the working dir as first arg (and cd's there) and passes the rest to the program, which you define as data dep.

Answer (score 9):

`bazel run` executes the binary within its runfiles tree, and [there is official no way to change that](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2579#issuecomment-626840214). Possible solutions if this is a problem:

- Don't use `bazel run`; execute the binary directly.
- `bazel run` puts the working directory it was executed from in the `$BUILD_WORKING_DIRECTORY` environmental variable, so the binary can resolve paths relative to that if desired.
- On platforms with a POSIX shell, there is a hacky workaround: `bazel run --run_under="cd $PWD &&" //some:target`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `sh_binary` then you can work around this with a script like so:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -e

LAUNCH_WORKING_DIRECTORY=$(pwd)

if test "${BUILD_WORKING_DIRECTORY+x}"; then
  cd $BUILD_WORKING_DIRECTORY
fi

$LAUNCH_WORKING_DIRECTORY/tool.sh "${@:1}"
```

```py
sh_binary(
  name = "tool",
  srcs = [ "launcher.sh" ],
  data = [ "tool.sh" ],
)
```

Bazel makes this absurdly complicated, it must be said.